# LIKE operator in XQL

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery, webmethods

I am doing some XML parsing in webMethods which only supports XQL, not XPath/XQuery.

I'm trying to find the LIKE operator to do a wildcard search on an attribute value

```
/MAP[@MODE='INPUT']/MAPSET[@FIELD LIKE '/documentTypeName*']/DATA/Values/value
```

In XQuery, I was using the matches() function. Have been surprised at my lack of finding an answer through searching. My best bet was http://www.ibiblio.org/xql/xql-proposal.html which says it should be keyword *contains* but this doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much a necro, but i believe you are looking for 'icontains'. 
http://www.ibiblio.org/xql/xql-proposal.html#Comparisons
Section 1.4.3 Comparisons. This should be a case insensitive version of 'contains'

```
(field icontains "/documentTypeName*")
```